# EF6 error when inserting row directly in table

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Using EF6, .NET Core 5, SQL Server

Using the 2 classes below I create 2 related tables in VS2019 using Package Manager Console and entityframework.

```
    public class ReservFile
    {
       [Key]
       [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]      // This value retrieved from a counter.
       public int IdNo { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       [ForeignKey("ReFileIdNo")]
       public List<ReservItem> ReservItems { get; set; }  
    } 
    
    public class ReservItem
    {
    [Key]
    public int IdNo { get; set; }
    public int ReFileIdNo { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    } 
    
    
    // This works if I insert using the ReservFiles table
    ...
    newRow = new ReservFile);
    newRow.IdNo = getValueFromCounter();
    newRow.Name = 'Joe';
    newRow.ReservItems.Add( new Item { RaFileIdNo = newRow.IdNo, Code = 'ggg', Description = 'kkkk'}); 
    db.ReservFiles.Add(newRow)
    db.SaveChanges();
    ...
    
    
    // But if I try to insert just items for an existing row directly in ReservItems This gives error:
    InnerException = {"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'ReservItems' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."}
    
    newItem = new ReservItem();
    newItem.RaFileIdNo = newRow.IdNo;
    newItem.Code = 'ggg';
    newItem.Description = 'kkkk';
    db..Add(newItem);
    db.SaveChanges();
    
    
    // Then I try this and gives the error:
    InnerException = {"Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'ReservItems' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column."}
    
    db.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[ReservItems] ON");
    db..Add(newItem);
    db.SaveChanges();
    db.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[ReservItems] OFF");
    
    
    // Then I try this and gives the error:
    InnerException = {"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_dbo.ReservAdtlCharges_dbo.ReservFiles_ReservFile_IdNo\". The conflict occurred in database \"RPRentalPlus\", table \"dbo.ReservFiles\", column 'IdNo'.\r\nThe statement has been terminate...
    
    newItem.IdNo = 3316  (This is one more than the last one in the table)
    newItem.RaFileIdNo = newRow.IdNo;
    newItem.Code = 'ggg';
    newItem.Description = 'kkkk';

   db.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[ReservItems] ON");
    db..Add(newItem);
    db.SaveChanges();
    db.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[ReservItems] OFF");
```

I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the way to obtain a primary key for ReserveItem. And you didn' t assign RaFileIdNo in your last example. And you don'nees to add the item to the whole dbcontext. Use db Set for this

Try this

```
newItem = new ReserveItem();
newItem.IdNo = 3316 //or how you get primary key, 3316 could be used already
newItem.RaFileIdNo = newRow.IdNo; 
newItem.Code = 'ggg';
newItem.Description = 'kkkk';
db.Set<ReserveItem>().Add(newItem);
db.SaveChanges();
```